# What do each of the Visual Studio Code Intellisense Icons mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, intellisense

What do all the icons represent when viewing the options IntelliSense provides? IntelliSense isn't the only place we would see these icons, but I'm using it as an example in the hope that someone can identify these icons, and explain what they mean.

[image: Screenshot depicting a modal window of 3 different IntelliSense icons in Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A list of icons and their names and descriptions is available on the [Microsoft Docs page on IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions). Here is the full list:

[image: Intellisens/suggestion icons and their meanings]

| Light Icon | Dark Icon | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Methods and Function icon; white background] | [image: Methods and Function icon; transparent background] | Methods and Functions | `method`, `function`, `constructor` |
| [image: Variable icon; white background] | [image: Variable icon; transparent background] | Variables | `variable` |
| [image: Field icon; white background] | [image: Field icon; transparent background] | Fields | `field` |
| [image: Type Parameter icon; white background] | [image: Type Parameter icon; transparent background] | Type parameters | `typeParameter` |
| [image: Constant icon; white background] | [image: Constant icon; transparent background] | Constants | `constant` |
| [image: Class icon; white background] | [image: Class icon; transparent background] | Classes | `class` |
| [image: Interface icon; white background] | [image: Interface icon; transparent background] | Interfaces | `interface` |
| [image: Structure icon; white background] | [image: Structure icon; transparent background] | Structures | `struct` |
| [image: Event icon; white background] | [image: Event icon; transparent background] | Events | `event` |
| [image: Operator icon; white background] | [image: Operator icon; transparent background] | Operators | `operator` |
| [image: Module icon; white background] | [image: Module icon; transparent background] | Modules | `module` |
| [image: Properties and Attributes icon; white background] | [image: Properties and Attributes icon; transparent background] | Properties and Attributes | `property` |
| [image: Values and Enumerations icon; white background] | [image: Values and Enumerations icon; transparent background] | Values and Enumerations | `value`, `enum` |
| [image: Reference icon; white background] | [image: Reference icon; transparent background] | References | `reference` |
| [image: Keyword icon; white background] | [image: Keyword icon; black background] | Keywords | `keyword` |
| [image: File icon; white background] | [image: File icon; transparent icon] | Files | `file` |
| [image: Folder icon; white background] | [image: Folder icon; transparent background] | Folders | `folder` |
| [image: Color icon; white background] | [image: Color icon; transparent background] | Colors | `color` |
| [image: Unit icon; white background] | [image: Ruler icon; transparent background] | Unit | `unit` |
| [image: Snippet icon; white background] | [image: Snippet icon; transparent background] | Snippet prefixes | `snippet` |
| [image: String icon; white background] | [image: String icon; black background] | Words | `text` |

Comment: Discussed this with other mods and we're on the fence here. I went back and added a separate column for light and dark. In light mode, it looks fine. In dark mode, the "dark" column is transparent so you see the dark icons on a darker background. The benefit of the table is that it should simplify maintaining this list going forward (someone added an answer with yet another image, which is how we got started on this). While it might not be ideal in dark mode, light mode is still the default and it's not clear the image does better. Feel free to ping me if you still disagree.

Comment: @Machavity I will fix by adding the original image as well.  The light icons in dark mode are very poor, and most of the dark icons in dark mode are light ghosts.   This is what I see https://imgur.com/a/CHGSaNV.  And note that is magnified a little.  Do you see aomething better?

Comment: I don't see anything better, but most of the folks finding this will see it on a white background (SO doesn't exactly advertise dark mode). I certainly don't want to make you uncomfortable (it *is* your post after all), but I also don't want to see a useful table thrown away either solely for an image (which we [tend to view as less useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2370483) in most contexts). I am fine with your adding the image back in alongside the table.

Comment: A further revision (when I have time, since it takes quite a bit of it) will see the removal of the "Dark Icon" column as that column is not actually necessary (the light mode of Stack Overflow lets you see the "Light Icon" column just fine, given that both the icons and the site background are white). Makyen did recommend looking up to see if there are any actual _VS Code dark mode_ versions of the icons, but since I don't even know if that exists, I'm not sure if that'll wind its way into the upcoming revision or yet another one.

Comment: The table and image are perfect together in the same post.  I do love the new table with both columns... we have the best of all worlds.  It has been marked as the NEW correct answer.

Comment: Note: The source SVG files can be found on GitHub at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-icons (not coloured with the same colours as used in the suggestions UI though)