# Weird snippet in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Does anybody know what this weird snippet is? It doesn't expand into anything.

These block-looking snippets underneath are VSCode's built-in snippets, but this first one is useless and it forces me to press the down arrow every time I want to use any loop. It doesn't have anything to do with my extensions and options and I can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a snippet, `for` is a keyword in the language you're coding. So it's just a suggestion for code completion.

In Python `def` is a keyword to create functions:

[image]

Check [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) from document to see the explanation of the other icons.

Also if "pressing down arrow" bothers you, you have an option to set the visibility of the snippets on the top of the suggestion list:

```json
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

Comment: This is also pretty useful too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678479/what-do-each-of-the-visual-studio-code-intellisense-icons-mean