# What extension is causing my custom php snippets to get overwritten, and how can I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot of completions for db]

If this is due to an extension, how can I remove that extension?

It overwrites my custom snippet, which bothers me.

I disabled many extensions, but nothing changed.

Comment: I think its built in feature

Comment: How can I sort my custom snippet to be first in the list?

Comment: they are not snippets, a snippet has an open square as icon

Comment: what are they？！

Comment: `Edito > Snippet Suggestions: Top` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing in your screenshot (suggestions for `dba_<etc.>`) are not coming from any extension. One can verify that by running the command `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` and trying triggering suggestions again. So this is just functionality that comes out-of-box with a standard VS Code installation. You don't even need to install any PHP extension to get this.

As for your custom snippets getting "overwritten", it's hard to tell without more detail why this is happening. If you're on version 1.75, it might just be due to a bug that will be fixed later (Ex. As was the case in this other recent Q&A: [Visual Studio Code's recent update is disrupting autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75340072/11107541)).

As [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark) showed in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75341123/11107541), these are function suggestions. You can disable function suggestions with the following setting:

> ```json
> "[php]": {
>   "editor.suggest.showFunctions": false
> }
> ```

Comment: Really, you are amazing
My version is 1.75
And the problem really doesn't come from the extension

Answer (score 1):

Those icons indicate that those are `Methods and Functions` (not Snippets).  See [What do the Intellisense icons mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57679985/836330).

So you can try to disable two settings in your Settings UI:

```
Editor > Suggest: Show Methods
Editor > Suggest: Show Functions  - this looks like the right one to disable
```

Of course, there might be situations where you want to see Function suggestions, so you will have to see if disabling the setting is acceptable.

You can disable those Function suggestions for `php` files only with this setting (in your `settings.json`):

```
"[php]": {
  "editor.suggest.showFunctions": false
}
```

Comment: u r  amazing

i succeeded